# Why is "1,2,3" parsed as 123 by Java's en-US DecimalFormat?

Tags: java, parsing, decimal, number-formatting, decimalformat

Parsing "*1,2,3*" using the *en-US*'s decimal format results in the number 123.

```java
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        final String text = "1,2,3";
        final int weirdResult = 123;

        final NumberFormat usDecimalFormat = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
        final Number parsedNumber = usDecimalFormat.parse(text);

        if(parsedNumber.doubleValue() == weirdResult){
            System.out.println(text + " is bizarrely parsed as " + weirdResult);
        } else {
            System.out.println(text + " is parsed as " + parsedNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

[Run on Ideone](https://ideone.com/xaMmrq)

The above code actually prints `1,2,3 is bizarrely parsed as 123`.

How is "1,2,3" a valid number and why its value is 123?

Comment: Because the `,` is used as a _thousands separator_ in US and British english formats, I suppose this is simply ignored in the input string.

Answer (score 2):

`DecimalFormat` has an internal method, `#subparse`, which takes care of interpreting separators and other special characters (dependent on the `Locale` that you have passed in). It will track the characters of interest (like digits, the decimal separator, or currency symbols), but of particular interest is how "grouping separators" (e.g. `,` in UK, `.` in France) are handled when doing this parse:

```
char grouping = symbols.getGroupingSeparator();
//...
for (; position < text.length(); ++position) {
    char ch = text.charAt(position);
    //...
    } else if (!isExponent && ch == grouping && isGroupingUsed()) {
        if (sawDecimal) {
            break;
        }
        // Ignore grouping characters, if we are using them, but
        // require that they be followed by a digit.  Otherwise
        // we backup and reprocess them.
        backup = position;
    } //...
}
```

Source: [DecimalFormat.java:2290](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-21+14/src/java.base/share/classes/java/text/DecimalFormat.java#L2465-L2472) (Note: The above was [refactored](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/4a28e27fd2f4f6f8ff2142e9f4696f622a9ecb1f#diff-2c34b675133fa96e6f7d7ebe4bf58f6a6680ec5cc4b96e0b8853c2885ee2a712) into `#subparseNumber` as of JDK 12)

Note the `break` means to finish parsing the number, and the lack of appending to `digitList` means they effectively ignore these grouping separators. Further, the ignoring of these grouping separators is not dependent on how many digits have been parsed since the last separator. The only conditional based on previous separators is if the grouping separator appears *after* the decimal separator, hence the `break`.

Comment: Obs: The break means to finish parsing if we're past the decimal separator (sawDecimal). That's why "0.1,2,3" is parsed as 0.1 (and not 0.123).

Comment: That's correct, it considers a grouping separator past the decimal as the end of the number.

Comment: This gracefully explains "how" the parsing code does that. But not "why". Is it a bug? Is "1,2,3" a valid number?

Comment: I'm not sure why they opted for it personally, but I would guess that as the placement of a grouping separator doesn't change the overall number if removed, they figured it was safe to ignore them while parsing (e.g. `12,345.67` -> `12345.67` is the same number, but `123.45` -> `12345` is not). I did not find a justification from a brief read of the surrounding commentary and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> This explains "how" the parsing code does that. But not "why". Is it a bug? Is "1,2,3" a valid number?

The why is that they decided to treat the "grouping" character (which in EN locales is `','`) leniently when parsing.  After all, the use of grouping characters ... and the number of digits in the groups ... are only conventions.  Lenient parsing is generally a good idea when dealing with inputs whose meaning is not ambiguous.  (Though that is debatable here.)

Basically, in most contexts the grouping character is quietly ignored when parsing.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition)) for the `DecimalFormat.parse` method doesn't mention this.  However, the javadoc is largely silent on the format that the method accepts, so the behavior is not inconsistent with the documentation.

This was reported as bug [JDK-7049000](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7049000) against Java 6 back in 2011, but you can see the bug report has received no attention.

And here's the problem.  If they did try to do something to fix this bug / feature, the fix would be liable to cause problems for existing applications.  These apps could reject inputs that they previously accepted ... for no particularly good reason from the users' point of view.

---

So, my advice would be to accept `DecimalFormat` for what it is.  If you particularly don't want to accept numbers with grouping characters:

- use `DecimalFormal.setDecimalFormatSymbols` to set the grouping separator to some character that can never appear, or
- validate or split your input numbers with (say) a regex prior to parsing them.

Comment: Point up the JDK's issue kind of settled it up. Thanks. If you had the time and willing to post it as a new, concise, self-contained answer, I would accept it right away. Or I could write it myself, if you don't mind..

Comment: No thanks.  A simple answer that says "it is a bug" is missing the point.  Yes, it was reported as a bug ... and the example in the bug report is more convincing.  But you should note that there is no commentary in the report that confirms that the behavior is wrong.  Indeed, this is a problem where there is no unambiguously correct solution.  And I'm not going to write an answer that implies that there is.  IMO, the existence of the bug report does not "settle" the issue at all.